# tocloft adding text after titles

Tags: tocloft

The [tocloft docs](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf#subsection.2.2) suggest that the command `\cftaftertoctitle` provides a means to insert stuff between the toc title and the actual toc contents.  However, it doesn't seem to do anything.  Specifically, in that section, the manual claims that:

> Doing:
>
> \renewcommand{\cftafterZtitle}{%
>         \[\baselineskip]\mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}}
>
> will put the word ‘Page’ flushright on the line following the title.

This is actually precisely the behavior I wish to enable.  However, those lines do not seem to do anything at all:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % Alter the style of the Table of Contents

\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{%
    \\[\baselineskip]\mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Local Gaussian Process Features for Clinical Sensor Time Series} \label{chapter:localgpr}
\chapter{Decision Surfaces of Localized Classifiers} \label{chapter:localsvm}
\chapter{Local Word2Vec Models over Time} \label{chapter:localw2v}
\chapter{Local Orthogonal Quadric Regression} \label{chapter:localodq}
\section{Gaussian Process Weighting} \label{appendix:gprweights}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I put stuff into the space between the title and the toc with `tocloft`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the `tocloft` package with the option `titles` *deactivates* all commands related to modifying the appearance of the titles of the ToC, the LoF, and the LoT. See section 2.1, "Package Options", on p. 7 of the package's user guide (emphasis added):

[image]

Now, section 2.2, "Changing the Titles", is precisely what you refer to in your posting and infer that "it [the package's commands] doesn't seem to do anything".

What to do? Load the `tocloft` package *without* the option `titles`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you are after. Please show the output you are after. The `\cftaftertoctitle` can be used to change the look of the `Table of Contents` title. Is that what you want?

If you want to put something between the individual titles and their page numbers then look at something like `\cftchapleader{Some text}` but changed to be suited to your needs.